# What are the common risks would there be in running the Debian testing instead of stable on Webserver

Tags: linux

So, as the question says, I'm looking to migrate my server from Debian Wheezy to Debian Jessie (testing). 
What are the risks? Stability?
How to avoid risks but still have the latest packages like in testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately using the testing branch there is no way to ensure stability.

You are, by definition, using packages that are still in testing.

You have to ask yourself what the real benefits to using the newer packages are and decide if the risk is worth the reward.

How critical is the server, what are the costs of crashing? If this is a personal server for home use, it might be worth it. If this is a production server in a professional environment I would recommend against it